# template mode loop behavior

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I want to generate a simple tree structure from xml via xslt transformation.

The xml source looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xslt"?>
<root>
    <pi>
        <id>P1</id>
        <s>
            <sc>
                <id>SC1</id>
                <si>
                    <id>SI1</id>
                </si>
                <sc>
                    <id>SC2</id>
                    <si>
                        <id>SI2</id>
                    </si>
                    <si>
                        <id>SI3</id>
                    </si>
                </sc>
            </sc>
            <sc>
                <id>SC3</id>
                <si>
                    <id>SI4</id>
                </si>
            </sc>
            <si>
                <id>SI6</id>
            </si>
        </s>
    </pi>
</root>
```

This is my xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                <title> Test </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1> Test </h1>
                <xsl:for-each select=".">
                    <xsl:call-template name="PH"/>
                    <div>
                        <xsl:call-template name="Structure"/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Header -->
    <xsl:template name="PH" match="//pi">
        <div>
            <h2> PI </h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Identifier:</td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="//pi/id"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Structure -->
    <xsl:template name="Structure" match="//s">
        <div>Structure</div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//s/sc"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//s/si"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Container -->
    <xsl:template match="//s/sc" mode="loop">
        <div><xsl:value-of select="id"/></div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//sc/sc" mode="loop">
        <div><xsl:value-of select="id"/></div>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Item -->
    <xsl:template name="StructueItem" match="//s/si">
        <div><xsl:value-of select="id"/></div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="StructueItem1" match="//sc/si">
        <div><xsl:value-of select="id"/></div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would expect, that in the generated HTML are all HTML tags and content from the xml source included. But there are no surrounding div tags for all sc xml elements in the transformation result.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Test </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> Test </h1>
      <div>
         <h2> PI </h2>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Identifier:</td>
               <td>P1</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div>
         <div>Structure</div>
         SC1      
         <div>SI1</div>
         SC2
         <div>SI2</div>
         <div>SI3</div>
         SC3
         <div>SI4</div>
         <div>SI6</div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what the expected output should be? Thanks!

Comment: Note that one "mistake" you have made is that you have two template matches with a `mode` set to "loop" but you don't have any `xsl:apply-templates` anywhere that use this mode, and so these templates will never get matched.

Comment: The result should looks like that:  <div>
    <div>Structure</div>
    <div>SC1 
        <div>SI1</div>
    </div>
    <div>SC2 
        <div>SI2</div>
        <div>SI3</div>
    </div>
    <div> SC3 
        <div>SI4</div>
    </div>
    <div>SI6</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The first remark concerning your source XML:
As you expect `<div>SI6</div>` to be under `SC3`, I think that

```
<si>
  <id>SI6</id>
</si>
```

should be "moved up" - inside the `<sc>` element just above.

I made a few changes to your script.

1. Instead of calling `Structure` template, I moved its content
   (with a little exception) to the place of call.
2. As you call some templates "by name" (and not "by matching"),
   I removed `match` attribute from them, to make the script more clear.
3. As the root node is only one, the `for-each` loop in the main template
   (matching "/") is not needed.
4. The basic idea is that from the main template I apply templates **only**
   to all descendant `sc` elements.
5. The template matching `sc`, in turn, first prints its own `id` element
   and then applies templates to its children `si` elements.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/><title> Test </title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1> Test </h1>
        <xsl:call-template name="PH"/>
        <div>
          <div>Structure</div>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//sc"/>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Header -->
  <xsl:template name="PH">
    <div>
      <h2> PI </h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Identifier:</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="//pi/id"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sc">
    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="si"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="si">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
    </div>  
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For a working example see http://xsltransform.net/3MEbY6F
It works under both *Xalan* and *Saxon* engines.